# Go from second fragment inside fragment activity to second fragment inside another activty

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

The scenerio of my some part of my app is as below:

[image]

The problem I'm stuck at is, I'm in the `EnterChildExpFragment`. I want to go to `ChildDetailsFragment` (which is in ChildExpensesActivity).

I can't share the whole code here. but I can tell some part of what I've been doing until now for going to `ChildDetailsFragment` from `EnterChildExpFragment`. 
First I tried: `((MainActivityExpenses)getActivity()).setCurrentItem(1, true);` But this shows up an error : `cannot cast fragmentactivty to activity`.

Then I tried :

```
ChildDetailsFragment childDetailsFragment = new ChildDetailsFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.replace(R.layout.child_details_fragment_layout,childDetailsFragment);
fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

But this also shows error: `No view found for id 0x7f...`

Note: Pl don't suggest me to use change the design or to merge `EnterChi...` fragments in `ChildExpenseActivity`.

I've kind of made nested fragments without using `parent-child` concept for fragments.

More info: In `ChildExpenseActivity`, I've used `Viewpager` and loaded the fragments in `getItem` method of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.
`AddChildFragmentActivity` is a FragmentActivity and has tabs in `ActionBar`.

TIA!

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I can't share my code. I've explained little what I've done in the question

Comment: *I want to go to ChildDetailsFragment (which is in ChildExpensesActivity).* - start a new Intent to go to `ChildExpensesActivity` and in its `onCreate()` callback show the `ChildDetailsFragment` fragment. You can't do transactions(or mix) between fragments from different activities.

Answer (score 0):

After cracking my head and doing some "jugaad" , finally I got want I wanted.

In `EnterChildExpFragment` I wrote this code snippet:

```
MainActivityExpenses.myBoolean=true;
Intent myIntent = new Intent(viewEnterChildExp.getContext(), MainActivityExpenses.class);
myIntent.putExtra("fromEnterChildExpToMainActivityExpenses", "true");
startActivity(myIntent);
getActivity().finish();
```

And in `ChildExpenseActivity`  :

```
public static Boolean myBoolean=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_expenses);

    viewPagerMainActivityExpenses = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerExpenses);
    viewPagerMainActivityExpenses.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

//        try {

        if (myBoolean) {
//                myBoolean = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("fromEnterChildExpToMainActivityExpenses");
            myBoolean=false;
            viewPagerMainActivityExpenses.setCurrentItem(1,true);
        }
    /*} catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("intent error","is : "+e.toString());
    }*/
}
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                return ChildFragment.newInstance();
            }
            case 1: {
                return ChildDetailsFragment.newInstance();
            }
            case 2: {
                return SomeFragment.newInstance();
            }

            default: {
                return SomeDefaultFragment.newInstance();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}

public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    viewPagerMainActivityExpenses.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}
```

Comment: PS.: `ChildExpenseActivity` and `ChildExpenseActivity` is same.  I mistakenly interchanged it. I wanted to let know before anyone gets confused.