# Cannot resolve finish() in intent in Fragment in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(viewEnterChildExp.getContext(), MainActivityExpenses.class);
myIntent.putExtra("fromEnterChildExpenseToMainActivityExpenses", "true");
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

I'm using the above code snippet in `fragment`

The `finish()` is in red color.

When I put mouse cursor over it, an error is popped:

```
can resolve method finish()
```

TIA!

Comment: what do you want by finish do you want to finish your activity ?

Comment: No, not activity. I want to go to [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002898/go-from-second-fragment-inside-fragment-activity-to-second-fragment-inside-anoth?noredirect=1#comment46253614_29002898). I found [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002898/go-from-second-fragment-inside-fragment-activity-to-second-fragment-inside-anoth?noredirect=1#comment46253614_29002898) for it and applying in my program.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `getActivity().finish();` from `Fragment` to finish Activity in which current fragment is attached

Comment: getActivity.finish(); should be getActivity().finish();

Answer (score 3):

You have to use activity instance for finish it.

Call `getActivity().finish()`

Comment: This is the same as other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The method `finiah()` is not applicable for fragment.
You must use `getActivity().finish();` instead, if you want to finish your activity in the fragment.